# Java Swing getvalue from combobox object

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, import, combobox

I made simple project in Java using swing. Below is code, I would like to get selected value from combobox placed in table, how I can do this? Good to be if thats data were placed in array. Thx for all answers.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
 public class SWD_GUI implements ActionListener {

        JButton button;
        public JFrame frame;
        private JTable table;
        private JTable table_1;
        private JTable table_2;
        private JTable table_3;
        private JFormattedTextField formattedTextField;
        JComboBox<ComboItem> comboBox;
         TableColumn column_1;


        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                try {
                                        SWD_GUI window = new SWD_GUI();
                                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                                } 
                                    catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                });
        }

        /**
         * Create the application.
         */
        public SWD_GUI() {
                initialize();

        }

        public void initialize() {
                frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 846, 546);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //frame.pack();
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

                JLabel lblSwdTelephone = new JLabel("SWD TELEPHONE");
                lblSwdTelephone.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                lblSwdTelephone.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
                lblSwdTelephone.setBounds(10, 11, 810, 20);
                frame.getContentPane().add(lblSwdTelephone);

                button = new JButton("DO IT!");
                button.setBounds(379, 432, 89, 23);
                frame.getContentPane().add(button);
                button.addActionListener(this);

                createTables();
        }

        private void createTables() {
                createFirstTable();
                createSecondTable();
                createThirdTable();
                createFourthTable();
        }



        private void createFourthTable() {
                TableModel tableModel_3 = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                                { "BATTERY", "Samsung", "HTC", "LG" },
                                { "Samsung", new Double(1.0), null, null },
                                { "HTC", null, new Double(1.0), null },
                                { "LG", null, null, new Double(1.0) }, }, new String[] {
                                "New column", "Price", "Specification", "Baterry" }) {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };
                        boolean[] rowEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };

                        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                                return columnEditables[column] && rowEditables[row];
                        }

                };

                createTable(table_3, tableModel_3, 304);
        }

        private void createThirdTable() {
                TableModel tableModel_2 = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                                { "SPECIFICATION", "Samsung", "HTC", "LG" },
                                { "Samsung", new Double(1.0), null, null },
                                { "HTC", null, new Double(1.0), null },
                                { "LG", null, null, new Double(1.0) }, }, new String[] {
                                "New column", "Price", "Specification", "Baterry" }) {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };
                        boolean[] rowEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };

                        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                                return columnEditables[column] && rowEditables[row];
                        }

                };

                createTable(table_2, tableModel_2, 214);
        }

        private void createSecondTable() {
                TableModel tableModel_1 = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                                { "PRICE", "Samsung", "HTC", "LG" },
                                { "Samsung", new Double(1.0), null, null },
                                { "HTC", null, new Double(1.0), null },
                                { "LG", null, null, new Double(1.0) }, }, new String[] {
                                "New column", "Price", "Specification", "Baterry" }) {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };
                        boolean[] rowEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };

                        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                                return columnEditables[column] && rowEditables[row];
                        }

                };

                createTable(table_1, tableModel_1, 124);
        }

        private void createFirstTable() {
                TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                                { null, "Price", "Specification", "Baterry" },
                                { "Price", new Double(1.0), null, null },
                                { "Specification", null, new Double(1.0), null },
                                { "Baterry", null, null, new Double(1.0) }, }, new String[] {
                                "New column", "Price", "Specification", "Baterry" }) {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };
                        boolean[] rowEditables = new boolean[] { false, true, true, true };

                        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                                return columnEditables[column] && rowEditables[row];
                        }

                };

                createTable(table, tableModel, 39);
        }

        private void createTable(JTable table, TableModel tableModel, int y) {
                table = new JTable();
                table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
                table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                table.setBounds(10, y, 424, 64);
                frame.getContentPane().add(table);
                table.setModel(tableModel);
                addColumn(table, 1);
                addColumn(table, 2);
                addColumn(table, 3);


        }

        class ComboItem
        {
            public String key;
            public String value;

            public ComboItem(String key, String value)
            {
                this.key = key;
                this.value = value;
            }

            //@Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return key;
            }

            public String getKey()
            {
                return key;
            }

            public String getValue()
            {
                return value;
            }

        }

        public void addColumn(JTable table, int columnIndex) {
                {

                        TableColumn column_1 = table.getColumnModel()
                                        .getColumn(columnIndex);
                        JComboBox<Object> comboBox = new JComboBox<Object>();
                        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("1", "1.0"));
                        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("3", "3.0"));
                        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("5", "5.0"));
                        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("7", "7.0"));
                        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("1/3", "0.333333333"));
                        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("1/5", "0.2"));
                        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("1/7", "0,1428571428571429"));

                        //comboBox.addItem((double) 1);
                       //comboBox.addItem((double) 3);
                        //comboBox.addItem((double) 5);
                        //comboBox.addItem((double) 7);
                        //comboBox.addItem((double) 9);
                        //comboBox.addItem((double) (1.0/3.0));
                        //comboBox.addItem((double) (1.0/5.0));
                        //comboBox.addItem((double) (1.0/7.0));
                        //comboBox.addItem((double) (1.0/9.0));


                        column_1.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));


                        Object item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                        String value = ((ComboItem)item).getValue();
                        System.out.println(value);
                        }


                formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
                formattedTextField.setBounds(462, 36, 358, 333);
                frame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextField);


        }

        //public void getContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //}  
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stud
                Object source = e.getSource();
                if (source == button) {


                }
                //for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
                //System.out.println(anArrays[i]);
                //}

       //           getContents();

                //int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                //String idS = table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
                //String al = column_1.getMaxWidth().toString();
                //System.out.println(al);

//                  System.out.println(item);


              //  formattedTextField.add(table);
                //formattedTextField.setValue(table);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the data from the table, not the combo box.

```
ComboItem item = (ComboItem)table.getValueAt(...);
System.out.println( item.getValue() );
```

Comment: Ok, thx. But now I trying and not working. Maybe I must just add actionlistener for table?

Comment: No, you don't add an ActionListener to the table. You invoke that code in response to some other user event. I would guess you invoke that code when the "Button" is clicked.